# Raspberry PI Serial Data Inconsistent

Tags: raspbian, uart, gps

So I'm working on a GPS system which uses the UART on the Raspberry Pi to communicate with. Ths GPS Im using is a GNSS CLICK 7 from Mikroe combinded with the Pi 2. I have these commands run on startup,

```
/usr/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 38400 (The GPS is configured at 38400)
/usr/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 -echo
```

and then when I run the command, sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0 half the time I will get valid good data as desired and the other half is gibberish data like this:

```
$ sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0
▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ݱ▒Ź▒▒▒bj▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒▒5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒ѱ▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ű▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒▒▒bbbb▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒ѱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒bb▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9I5
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ͱ▒▒
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ű▒Ź▒▒▒bj▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒▒5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒ѱ▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒25)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒▒▒▒▒bbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒
5)▒9I5
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ͱ▒▒▒Y▒▒
PuTTY▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ű▒Ź▒▒ͱj▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒▒5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒ѱ▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒25)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒▒▒▒▒bbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY5)▒9I5
▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ű▒Ź▒▒ٱj▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒▒5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒▒b▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒25)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒▒▒▒▒bbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY5)▒9I5
▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ű▒Ź▒▒▒j▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒
5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒▒b▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒25)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒▒▒▒▒bbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒
5)▒9I5
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ű▒Ź▒▒▒j▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒▒b▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒25)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒▒▒▒▒bbb▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rʊb▒r▒▒b▒R▒
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY5)▒9QaQ▒▒ű▒ű▒▒▒▒ՙ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒5)▒9I5
▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ݱ▒Ź▒▒ٱj▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒▒5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒▒b▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ű▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒ѱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒b▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9I5
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY▒ű▒ɱ▒▒ݱ▒Ź▒▒▒bj▒▒▒▒▒ɱ5▒▒▒▒▒5)▒9M▒▒ͱ▒ͱ▒▒▒ɱ▒ݱ▒ѱ▒▒b▒▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒ű▒ݱ▒ᱱ▒bbbbbb▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9M▒▒ͱ▒ٱ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒b▒rºb▒r▒▒b▒R▒▒jR":9I5
```

Tried:
Disabling Serial Console in /boot/cmdline.txt
Checked wiring/replaced wires
Set Parity, Stop Bits and Data Bits

I have a feeling it has something to do with Putty as its writing "PuTTY" everytime it spits out that rubbish but I have no clue.

Comment: Which Pi? What OS is installed (detail including version)? How is it connected? Why & how are you "run on startup"?

Comment: `something to do with Putty` ... I think Putty sends that when it receives a particular character - and since you're receiving random garbage, that character is likely coming up - so, it's nothing to do with Putty

Comment: If you stop using cat on non-text bytes over putty.  Dump to file and use a hexadecimal or other binary viewer, and look at the actual data values.  It may shed some light as to what is happening.  You do appear to have patterns of bytes so it may not truly be random.